Make/force my cellular network connection have static IP address, or manual IP
I live a conflict area with internet blocked. I have Samsung a54 phone. They block your internet by blacklisting IPs assigned by certain towers on network registering. eg. 10.111.. is blocked while 10.67.. is internet enabled.
When you come from another unrestricted area, already registered with an IP of that area, they let you use internet fine. And when you come to the restricted area it still works fine with all towers. That's until your device does re registers, either due to restart or the phone resetting network settings. If you re register at the restricted area towers, they will give you a not working IP. I have been forced to drive to other cities, register to a tower there, and come back. It works while the connection is still maintained, even in the restricted towers.
Unfortunately, most modern phones and android versions try to "optimize" your internet and will auto reset, reconnect, switch network... and there is no way to stop them. And that will stop the internet and create new connection with the restricted towers, with new IP.
I tried setting manual network selection, forcing 4g only with an app... Yet, they "optimize" it and reconnect anyway.
But it all comes down to IP address, since I can use internet with some subnet of IP addresses. How can I make it retain, as if I can do manual IP address on a wifi and it works well?
I already know they are dynamic. But looking for a way to force it and to make the device say "this is my IP" and get at least rejected, as you can do in any other networks, even DHCP wifi or ethernet networks, where you can give your device any IP and make it claim to have a given IP and the network will either reject or accept you. (most accept if there is no conflict or is in the subnet)
You can find your cellular IP at Settings>About>Status>IP Address
Edit: Happy to root my phone if there is any viable solution that way too.

A cellular tower the disallows Internet connection? Such a configuration isn't done by accident by the MNO. Are we talking about some special cellular tower that is e.g. located in a prison?

@Robert Conflict area. Area bigger than size of Bangladesh in internet lockdown. Implemented by blocking IPs assigned by towers in that area

Is getting an old model of cell phone that doesn't optimize the connection and use that to tether to your phone a viable option?

@beeshyams Yes old phones and some of the cheap Chinese portable wifi modems seem to work better. But they will eventually get reassigned randomly maybe due to the tower actions or IP lease expiry.

Thanks, Just made an edit
